# How to test whether the dependencies installed?

Tags: python, testing, import, module, dependencies

I've been learning `PyTorch` for deep learning recently.
Using *anaconda* I found some problems when I ran the program.
For example, I encountered the following import error

> "no module named kiwisolver"

when my program imported `matplotlib`. It is fixed, but such error is very frustrating. The program runs for a long time.

Is there any way to check whether all the required dependencies are installed?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your program is structured...

Many Python programs use the [`if __name__ == "__main__":` idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/25507) so that they don't immediately execute code.  This lets you import the code without it immediately running.

For example, if you have my_py_torch.py, then if you run `python` to [launch the Python interpreter in interactive mode](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html), you can import your code:

```
import my_py_torch
```

Importing your code will process any imports, execute any top-level code, and define any functions and classes, but, as long as you use the `if __name__ == "__main__":` idiom, it won't actually run the (long-running) code.  That's typically enough to let you know if you have major issues like syntax errors, bad imports, or missing dependencies.

Code can still circumvent this: you may have functions or methods that only import modules locally (when they're actually run), or code may wrap imports in `try` / `except` blocks to handle missing dependencies then later throw an error if the dependency is used.  So it's not foolproof, but it can be a useful test.